# Android, refresh listview on item clicked

Tags: android, android-listview

I know their are a lot of question relative to refreshing listView, but none of them are anwering my problem (as far as I know).

**I'm trying to change my item view when clicking on it in my list view.**

To change the view I've got a `boolean isClicked` on my POJO :

```
        networksListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> _adapter, View view, int pos, long id) {
            myApp.networksGlobal.networks.get(pos);
            myApp.networksGlobal.networks.get(pos).isClicked = !myApp.networksGlobal.networks.get(pos).isClicked;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

When I click on the item `isClicked` switch from true to false, and on my `getView` listAdapted I'm switching the view type :

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Network network = (Network) getItem(position);
    NetworkItemView networkItemView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        networkItemView = NetworkItemView_.build(context);
    } else {
        networkItemView = (NetworkItemView) convertView;
    }
    networkItemView.bind(network);
    if (network.isClicked) {
        networkItemView.networkItemButtonLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        networkItemView.networkItemButtonLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    return networkItemView;

}
```

On the first click everything is working great, the Toast is shown an the Layout `networkItemButtonLayout` is set to visible.

But if I click a second time on the same item : **nothing happend**. No Toast is shown and no changes on the Layout visibility.

If I comment `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` the Toast is shown for every click. So I guess the problem is why the call to `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. So tried several work around (`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` and `networksSearchListView.invalidateViews()`) but nothing do the trick, and I can't find a way to click several time on my item.

Does I'm using 'notifyDataSetChanged' the proper way ?

Comment: where  are you switching the isClicked  to true or false?

Comment: I'm switching the isClicked at every `networksSearchListViewItemClicked` so I can change the visibility of `networkItemButtonLayout` at every click (first click show the button Layout, second click hide the button Layout)

Comment: my guess is that `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` is getting called repeatedly and locking up your listview. i can only assume that for some reason, perhaps it's a rogue method and perhaps every item is percieved to be clicked and the method is ran more than once. using a conventional listview `ItemClickListener` might work better. of course i can only guess.

Comment: did you do that in the above method? android of @item click annotation?

Comment: I'm sorry G_S I don't understand you comment.

Comment: @mango : I'll tried without the @ItemClicked annotation. Do you think it is acceptable to use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` into an `ItemClickListener` ?

Comment: yeh of course, are your results any different?

Comment: I change my `ItemClickListener` and edit the question with the new code. I'm not using Android annotation to set the `ItemClickListener`. The comportement doesn't change only the first click is recognized. I think maybe I'm not managing correctly the arrayList used by my adapter, and so whe I'm changing the isClicked property on my global arralist, the arrayList of the adapter is not updated correctly

Comment: As you change the visibility of one item at a time you could make the visibility switch without the call to `notifyDataSetChanged`. In the `OnItemClickListener` : `myApp.networksGlobal.networks.get(pos).isClicked = !myApp.networksGlobal.networks.get(pos).isClicked; ((NetworkItemView)view).networkItemButtonLayout.setVisibility(myApp.networksGlobal.networks.get(pos).isClicked ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE)` . See how does this work.

Comment: Thank you for the try Luksprog. but I still have the same problem with you proposition. Only the first clic is recognized.

Comment: Did you tried without the `notifyDataSetChanged()` after my above code? Also, what View type is that `networkItemButtonLayout`(`Button`, composite layout etc)? What it's his startup state, visible or gone(meaning `isClicked` is first `true` or `false`)? As a side not please use @username (to get a notification) when replying otherwise users will not see your comment.